# Eagle routing (manual routing)

Tags: eaglecad, routing

I am new to eagle and I need to practice routing. I've read many general tips (about using jumpers for example) to use while routing, however I want a precise step by step procedure I can follow to manually do the routing for any circuit. Should i for example start by one part of the schematic and look at his corresponding part in the board? Any ideas?

Comment: Start with layout - nothing helps routing as much as good placement of components.

Comment: On that note, if the number of components is reasonable, you can drag them far apart in the boardview, roughly in the pattern you think they should be in, and I find that lets you unravel the spiderweb of air wires a bit easier.  If there was a concrete step by step process, it would be used by the autorouter.  I think people here could provide things more in lines of strategy or order of operation.  Once my component placement is OK, I like to autoroute over and over to try to get general solutions with few vias, and then hand route for nice looking swoopy traces and sich.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the procedure I use:

1. Create your desired board outline. If not defined by an enclosure, you may need to tweak it later on, but start with what you think you'll need. This would also be the time to determine how many layers you need and configure accordingly.
2. In the PCB layout editor, begin by placing your connectors and other human-interface items (buttons, switches, LEDs, etc). Usually you want to place these in a specific location on the board, to make it neat and clean (in a logical manner for human interface).
3. Mentally group together different parts of the schematic - Power, Microcontroller, Communication, Logic, etc. Pick which one you want to start with.
4. In the PCB layout editor, drag the components which are a part of the section you chose to start with and group them together (outside the board but separate from the other parts). You may have to break the larger section up into smaller groups, depending on the size. For example, the Power section of the schematic may have several voltage regulators, so do one regulator with its requisite circuitry as one group.
5. Within the single small group you just moved, start positioning the components in a logical manner that promotes the easiest routing (shortest, straightest airwires).
6. Within that single group, you may start routing the connections. Don't worry about the connections that go to different sections yet, just route what will be self-contained within that group.
7. Move the group onto the board and find a logical place for it.
8. Repeat steps 4-7 with the next group of components in the section, and then with the remaining sections.
9. Once all groups have been moved to the board and positioned where you want them (make sure to group parts within the Power section together, and parts within the microcontroller section together, and so on), you can start routing between the sections and do the human interface parts.
10. During the routing process you may find it much easier to place copper pours instead of individual traces, usually for power and ground connections. I normally do this right after I place all component sections on the board. This will minimize the airwires for ground or power that are visible and make it easier to identify which connections go group-to-group.

Sometimes you may need to do some of these steps out of order, but you'll get a better feel for it the more you practice. However, the process mentioned above should help you get started with routing just about any board.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Polygon to both layers and Name then GND. Place them  outside of the board Dimension lines.  Do to not run Gnd traces all over the board.  Add a few Vias and Name them GND also, that connect the top & bottom if you don't have thru hole parts connecting them.

Go into View:Grid and change the Grid 1 mil, that will let you place traces and parts pretty finely.

10 mil wide signal traces. 12 mil vias for signals.
20, 24mil wide for power, 24 or 32mil vias.